Why isn't my Audit Log event working with my Discord bot?
I am trying to get audit logs to work with my Discord bot. I've set up my bot according to the instructions on discordjs.guide. I am starting with trying to log when a message is deleted but it's just not doing anything. The following will show my index.js file and my auditLog.js event file.
Here is index.js:
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ 
    intents:[
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping
    ],
    partials:[Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction]
});

client.cooldowns = new Collection();
client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
    else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.login(token);

Here is auditLog.js
const { AuditLogEvent, Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.GuildAuditLogEntryCreate,
    async execute(auditLog) {
        const { action, channel, executorId, targetId } = auditLog;
        console.log("Audit log event triggered");

        if (action !== AuditLogEvent.MessageDelete) return;
        console.log(`Action: ${action}, ExecutorId: ${executorId}, TargetId: ${targetId}`);

        const executor = await client.users.fetch(executorId);
        const target = await client.users.fetch(targetId);

        console.log(`A message by ${target.tag} was deleted by ${executor.tag} in ${channel}.`);
    }
};

I have also tried adding the event directly in index.js to see if it would work like so:
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits, AuditLogEvent, Events } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ 
    intents:[
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping
    ],
    partials:[Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction]
});

client.cooldowns = new Collection();
client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
    else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

// Audit log event
client.on(Events.GuildAuditLogEntryCreate, async (auditLog) => {
    const { action, extra: channel, executorId, targetId } = auditLog;

    if (action !== AuditLogEvent.MessageDelete) return;

    const executor = await client.users.fetch(executorId);
    const target = await client.users.fetch(targetId);

    console.log(`A message by ${target.tag} was deleted by ${executor.tag} in ${channel}.`);
});

client.login(token);

As you can see I added debug logs console.log("Audit log event triggered"); and console.log(`Action: ${action}, ExecutorId: ${executorId}, TargetId: ${targetId}`); but these are not logging either. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong at this point. I do have the "View Audit Log" permission enabled on the bot, I've included a screenshot for reference. Granted Permissions
